# Sliding closet doors with 3 doors has narrowed opening

Tags: doors, interior, closet

I have a 83" width closet so I used two 72" closet doors. Basically, it is 3 doors on 2 tracks

[image]

However it is weird because the opening is way too small: 83-72 = 11"
It is because the front two doors are on the same track which is taking 72" space.

Here is the track

[image]

Is this installation done right?

**UPDATE**

This is the door I bought

https://www.lowes.com/pd/ReliaBilt-9205C-Series-White-6-Panel-Steel-Sliding-Closet-Door-Hardware-Included-Common-60-in-x-80-in-Actual-60-in-x-80-in/3040848

I got two of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a large door and the small door on one track - that will enable you to maximize the opening...

If you have 3 doors the same size, then install a 3rd track which means that all the doors can be in one spot maximizing the opening...

Comment: Each door is the same size

Comment: @HP. see the edit. When you said you used 2 72" doors I assumed that the 3rd was smaller...

Comment: I was thinking about the 3rd track option too but then the wall area on top is not wide enough. Plus there is not enough track to run. So I guess I am not sure if I use the correct parts for this scenario.

Comment: Make the area wider with a wood plank or similar...

Answer (score 0):

Is taking the doors back and getting 28" available to you? Or at least 2 being 28". This way you can have an overlap if you want, but also if you set up the 2 smaller doors on one track, larger 32" on the other, you then will have a maximum opening of 27". Another option is to make one door a swing open door on one side, the side with the wall, so that you swing that door out against the wall, the other 2 are pushed to the opposite side, this then gives you maybe 48"